# Using JavaScript, how do I combine items in two arrays parsed with forEach() into a single string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on an exercise that I can't find a solution for. This is the task:

> Create an array to hold your top choices (colors, presidents, whatever).
>
> 1. For each choice, log to the screen a string like: "My #1 choice is blue."
> 2. Change it to log "My 1st choice, "My 2nd choice", "My 3rd choice", picking the right suffix for the number based on what it is.

I have completed the first part of the task with the following:

```
const list = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
const prefs = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']; // For the second part

list.forEach((items, index, array) => {
  console.log(`My #1 choice is ${items} at position ${index} in the list that contains: ${array}`); // I included additional parameters to better understand the forEach() method
});
```

I can't work out how to complete the second part of the exercise that basically involves creating a string that links `list[0]` with `prefs[0]`, and iterates.

I saw [a possible, pre-ES6 solution](https://www.teaching-materials.org/javascript/exercises/arrays) for this that uses a really verbose `if` loop. What is an effective way to create the string required for the second part of the exercise? There must be a better solution than the one I saw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your lists are the same length:

```
list.forEach((items, index, array) => {
  console.log(`My ${prefs[index]} choice is ${items}.`);
});
```

Comment: `2. Change it to log "My 1st choice, "My 2nd choice", "My 3rd choice", picking the right suffix for the number based on what it is.`

Comment: sorry, my comment did sound a bit snappy which I just realised and was about to edit. I probably don't really understand what the question is asking, but I didnt think that is what he was looking for

Comment: Actually, that is pretty much spot on and I'm kicking myself that I didn't try that. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald no problem!

Comment: @PaulJacobson Also no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have index of list array, you can easily call prefs array with its index

```
const list = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
const prefs = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']; // For the second part

list.forEach((items, index, array) => {
    console.log(`My #${index+1} choice is ${items}`); // first part
    console.log(`My ${prefs[index]} choice is ${items}`); // second part
});
```

Alternatively, to ensure you have the same length of array, you can change it to two-dimensional array

```
const list2 = [
    ['first', 'blue'],
    ['second', 'green'],
    ['third', 'yellow'],
    ['fourth', 'red'],
];

list2.forEach((items, index, array) => {
    console.log(`My #${index+1} choice is ${items[1]}`); // first part
    console.log(`My ${items[0]} choice is ${items[1]}`); // second part
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the exercise hints at what you should be doing.  Notice that the prefs there are `1st`, `2nd`, etc and not "first" or "second".

The solution you found is the easiest way, I think, besides your solution of mapping out all of the possibilities.  English isn't very nice in that regard - though realistically you only have to map out 1-12 and then you can calculate through there. 21st = "twenty" + "first".

However, just checking what the ones digit is and doing

```
if((index+1) % 10 === 1){
  console.log(`my ${index+1}st choice is ${array[index]}`
}
```

and so on (or whatever) really is your best bet.  If you want it to look nicer you can make a function to return the ordinal.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I ignored the `1st`, `2nd` format and just focused on making the consolidated string work. Thanks for your suggestion, though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a robust solution that will handle any number properly...

const list = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', 'purple'];
const prefs = ['st', 'nd', 'rd']; // For the second part

```
const getNumWithSuffix = (i) => {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";  

}


list.forEach((items, index, array) => {
  console.log(`My ${getNumWithSuffix(index+1)} choice is ${items}.`);
});
```

Outputs...

```
My 1st choice is blue.
My 2nd choice is green.
My 3rd choice is yellow.
My 4th choice is red.
My 5th choice is purple.
```